# Java compiler swears generic incompatible types - compiler settings?

Tags: java, generics, compilation

Here is the Java 8 code of the project I support:

```
import static com.google.common.base.MoreObjects.*;
import static java.util.Collections.emptyList;

List<String> properties;
properties = firstNonNull(properties, emptyList());
```

It compiles locally well with Gradle but fails on Teamcity agent

```
[14:53:45][:admin-server:compileJava] .../PageRequest.java:24: error: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
[14:53:45][:admin-server:compileJava]         properties = firstNonNull(properties, emptyList());
[14:53:45][:admin-server:compileJava]                                  ^
[14:53:45][:admin-server:compileJava]     inferred: List<? extends Object>
[14:53:45][:admin-server:compileJava]     upper bound(s): List<String>,Object
[14:53:45][:admin-server:compileJava] Note: .../StatsResource.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[14:53:45][:admin-server:compileJava] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[14:53:45][:admin-server:compileJava] 1 error
```

What's wrong with it? I could probably fix it using

```
Collections.<String>emptyList()
```

but that seems not to be an option as it is not the only place where generics are not placed evidently. Thanks for help.

Comment: Sure teamcity actually compiles with javac 8?

Comment: Yes, Lambdas are used in code and they are compiled well

Comment: It is the real javac? not ecj or something like that? Can you paste more of your code, especially how you define declare properties?